# I need help walking through these vector problems including magnitude and direction.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors

Given the following vectors, answer the questions (a) through (d)
i. <2,-3> ii. -i+2(square root 3)j iii. <-2, 3> iv. i-3/2j

a.) Which vectors have the same direction but not the same magnitude?

b.) Which vectors have the same magnitude but not the same direction?

c.) Add vectors i. and iii. by drawing a picture below and also by using your unit vector addition.

d.) What is the magnitude and the direction of the resultant vector from (c.)?

Comment: pleae include what you tried

Comment: What specifically are you having trouble with?  These should be routine.  Just revisit your definitions.

Comment: Please write an *informative* title, relating to your specific problem—not one that could apply to every problem ever posted.

Comment: Because we don't have school, my teacher hasn't taught us anything. She just gave us this worksheet, we hadn't done anything with vectors prior to this. We also haven't done anything with magnitude or direction. So, I have no idea what I am doing. I've tried looking at youtube videos, Khan Academy, but I cannot relate it to this problem.@JMoravitz

Comment: If you have difficulty doing things purely via your own imagination... perhaps [drawing a picture might help](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=point+%282%2C-3%29%2C+point+%281%2C-3%2F2%29%2C+point+%28-2%2C3%29%2C+point+%28-1%2C2sqrt%283%29%29).

Comment: The end result is that the types of vectors you are talking about for now are going to be the simple examples where they are just tuples of numbers.  (*After several more semesters you might revisit the topic later and learn the true definitions for vectors in a general abstract sense*).  If you have a vector $(a,b)$ and a vector $(x,y)$ then you can add them by simply adding their respective entries... $(a,b)+(x,y)=(a+x,b+y)$, so for instance $(1,3)+(4,7)=(5,10)$

Comment: The magnitude of a vector, i.e. the length of the vector, in this context is going to be the simple example (*which again you'll learn the more abstract definition and more exotic examples later*) where all you have to do here is square each entry, add the results, then square root the result.  So, the magnitude of $(a,b)$ is $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$.  Remind you of triangles?  It should.  So, for instance, the magnitude of $(3,4)$ is $\sqrt{3^2+4^2}=\sqrt{25}=5$

Comment: The direction of a vector... well... two (*nonzero*) vectors are said to be going "in the same direction" if the one is just a positive multiple of the other.  If you were to look at the picture of them, treating them as points, two vectors are going in the same direction if they lie along the same ray originating from the origin.

Comment: Thank you @JMoravitz, this really helped.